What communities does the Girvan-Newman algorithm identify in a simple four-node graph?
The graph is structured as follows:
My question is: What communities would be found by the Girvan-Newman algorithm applied to
the graph?
Here are the options I'm considering:
A: {A, B, C, D}
B: {A}, {B}, {C}, {D}
C: Multiple results are possible
D: {B}, {A, C, D}
E: None of the previous answers

Which of these is the correct set of communities identified by the Girvan-Newman algorithm, and why? Any insights into the reasoning behind the answer would be greatly appreciated!

Welcome! For a small graph, it should be tenable to just run the algorithm by hand from either its Wikipedia definition or your textbook definition. Have you tried to do so, and if so, did you get stuck somewhere?
